# Why is/was Austria so strict about Google Street View?

Tags: privacy, austria

According to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverage_of_Google_Street_View#Current_coverage), Austria is one of the most restrictive countries when it comes to Google Street View coverage ("Only Museum views, business views and ski resorts.").

Germany is also careful when it comes to Street View, but it allows it in more areas ("20 biggest cities and ski resorts only.").

[This article](https://mattcornock.co.uk/digital-literacy/top10-googlestreetview/) deals with pros and cons of Google Street View and it clearly shows that its presence can lead to complex consequences.

**Question:** why does Austria seem to be much more restrictive as compared to other European countries about the Google Street View coverage?

**Note:** As `origimbo` correctly pointed out, it seems that Austria's coverage will increase, so my question is about low coverage until July 2017.

Comment: Note that this status may be about to change: https://phys.org/news/2017-07-google-street-view-captures-austria.html

Comment: I'm unsure what the question is asking. Is it asking why there's a policy difference? Because the relevant body setting the policy (executive or legislative) decided that way. Why did they decide that way? Then you need to ask what their stated motivations were (though if the stated motivations differ from linked article, I'll eat a page with my user profile printout)

Comment: @user4012 - Yes, I want to understand why is this policy difference. I know that both Germans and Austrians are more concern with their privacy than other Europeans, but I also noticed that Germany allows Street View in many major cities (although one may find a significant amount of blurred parts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I've read, many countries were reluctant to allow Google Maps and Google Street view to come to [Germany and Austria due to worries linked to data collection](https://phys.org/news/2017-07-google-street-view-captures-austria.html). In 2010, Google went to Austria and was ordered to stop its Street View operations over alleged claims of privacy breaches since the company had accidentally collected personal data and data from vehicles like registration plates. The ban on Google recorded data for Street View was temporarily lifted less than a year afterwards and Google resumed some degree of operations in 2017 with the data being made available in 2018, but even then, [faces and registration plates are blurred & Street View is mostly used for selected localities](https://bigthink.com/strange-maps/germany-street-view).

Comment: StreetView has been found to have 'accidentally collected' a lot of information, such as unprotected wi-fi traffic. Given the number of times that sort of thing has happened, it looks more like a directed effort than accidental.

Comment: @tj1000 that one was deliberately collected.